# "to_string" isn't a member of "std"?

Tags: c++, linux, string, c++11, g++

Okay, so I have

tmp.cpp:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::to_string(0);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile I get:

```
$ g++ tmp.cpp -o tmp
tmp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp.cpp:5:5: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
     std::to_string(0);
     ^
```

I'm running g++ version 4.8.1. Unlike all the other references to this error that I found out there, I am *not* using MinGW, I'm on Linux (3.11.2).

Any ideas why this is happening? Is this standard behaviour and I did something wrong or is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: With `g++ -std=c++11 -o tmp tmp.cc`, I get `error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'. g++ version is 4.8.2 . Is this a regression?

Comment: Mh, not sure, but it works for me on g++ 4.9.0

Comment: gcc --version using gcc tdm-2 4.8.1, compiling with -std=c++11 still yields error 'to-string' is not member of std

Comment: Same for me. With `arm-none-eabi-gcc -std=c++11` I still get the error.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you may want to specify the C++ version with

```
g++ -std=c++11 tmp.cpp -o tmp
```

I don't have gcc 4.8.1 at hand , but in older versions of GCC, 
you can use

```
g++ -std=c++0x tmp.cpp -o tmp
```

At least gcc 4.9.2 I believe also support part of C++14 by specifying

```
g++ -std=c++1y tmp.cpp -o tmp
```

Update:
gcc 5.3.0 (I am using the cygwin version) supports both `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++17` now.

Comment: Had this error in Eclipse CDT on Debian 8 (Linux 3.14-2-amd64). Specifying the GCC C++ Compiler in the settings to run the command `g++ -std=c++11` solved my issue! Thank you!

Comment: I still get the error in gcc --version tdm-2 4.8.1 when compiling with -std=c++11

Comment: I've also encountered this issue, it seems that std::to_string isn't available in gcc's standard library (libstdc++), it is however, available in libc++ which comes with LLVM/clang

Comment: what version of gcc you are using, you may also try -std=c++1y

Answer (score 25):

to_string works with the latest C++ versions like version 11. For older versions you can try using this function

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string ToString(T val)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << val;
    return stream.str();
}
```

By adding a template you can use any data type too.
You have to include  `#include<sstream>` here.

Comment: wouldn't it be more `safe` to use `std::ostringstream` since we only want the output of the stream?