# how to make multiple output from one input

Tags: c++, input, output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x, input1, input2;
string repeat;

int main() {
    while (repeat.compare("n") != 0) {
        cout << "input1 : ";
        cin >> input1; //input
        cout << "repeat?(y/n) ";
        cin >> repeat;
    }
    cout << input1; //output
}
```

if i run the code above, example input 1 y 7 y 5 n, the output of the code will only appear last number i input, how do i make them all printed out in cout ? dont tell me to make new variable with different name.

Comment: im changing the question, sorry for that

Comment: You can have a `vector<string> inputs;` and then `inputs.push_back(input1);` after reading it in, then `for (auto&& s : inputs) cout << s << "\n";` to output them all.

Comment: Replace with `vector<int> inputs;` for integers.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `while (repeat.compare("n") != 0)` really should be written `while (repeat != "n")`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the limitation you specified, we cannot make new variables. Then we use what we have.

We repurpose `repeat` to store the resulting string that will be the printed answer.

The "repeat" question now has an integer output so we don't waste a string variable on it. It sounds as `"repeat?(1 - yes / 0 - no)"`.

We repurpose `input2` to be a stop flag. If the "repeat?" question is answered as `0` [or a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080037/c-cin-reading-string-into-int-type-returns-0), the cycle stops.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x, input1, input2;
string repeat;

int main() {
    input2 = 1;
    while (input2 != 0) {
        cout << "input1 : ";
        cin >> input1;
        repeat += std::to_string(input1) + " ";
        cout << "repeat?(1 - yes / 0 - no) ";
        cin >> input2;
    }
    cout << repeat;
}
```

After that, the console log can look roughly like this:

```
input1 : 2
repeat?(1 - yes / 0 - no) 1
input1 : 45
repeat?(1 - yes / 0 - no) 1
input1 : 2374521
repeat?(1 - yes / 0 - no) 0
2 45 2374521
```

If you get an error about `std` not having `to_string()`, add `#include<string>` to the program. ([link to the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60927345/5859354))

Answer (score 0):

> the output of the code will only appear last number i input, how do i make them all printed out in cout ?

Just move the `cout` statement inside the while loop as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x, input1, input2;
string repeat;

int main() {
    while (repeat.compare("n") != 0) {
        cout << "input1 : ";
        cin >> input1; //input
        cout << "repeat?(y/n) ";
        cin >> repeat;
        cout << input1; //MOVED INSIDE WHILE LOOP
    }
   // cout << input1; //DONT COUT OUTSIDE WHILE LOOP
}
```

The program now output/print all entered numbers(inputs) as you want which can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/2BL3AVFPe).